# Convert date/time without year to this year

Tags: python, datetime

I'm taking input that looks like "8-15 14:45" and trying to turn it into a datetime object (and then turn it back into a string). My issue is that it sets the year to 1900, but I need the year set to this year. How do I accomplish this?

So far I have `datetime.datetime.strptime('8-15 14:45', '%m-%d %H:%M')` which gives me `datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 15, 14, 45)` but I need `datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 15, 14, 45)`. I'd like to not hardcode 2021 if I can help it.

Apologies if this is answered somewhere, my google-fu has failed me.

Comment: You can hardcode the format `'%m-%d %H:%M'` but you do not want to hardcode the year . . . why?

Comment: The system I'm polling uses that format and isn't going to change, but the actual date will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `datetime.replace` with datetime.today().year:

```
this_year = dt.datetime.today().year
dt.datetime.strptime('8-15 14:45', '%m-%d %H:%M').replace(year=this_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method now() of the datetime class and only ask for the property year of the returned datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.now().year
print(t)
>>> 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing the year on the parsed date like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
date = dt.strptime('8-15 14:45', '%m-%d %H:%M')
date = date.replace(year=dt.now().year)
```

Comment: `import datetime` `datetime.datetime.strptime('8-15 14:45', '%m-%d %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.datetime.now().year)`